# ASP Net MVC Core - Load User Data From Active Directory when User browses Any Page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

Here is my development environment:

- Intranet Website
- Active Directory Authentication/Authorization
- Asp Net Core

I am trying to get the data stored in Active Directory attributes when a user enters firstly to any page in our application.  All users rights and permissions, employeeid, studentid, etc.... are stored in AD Attributes **and** Security Groups.  Some Attributes need to be displayed on the website too.

Let's say my website got the following urls...

- http://mysite/Home/Index
- http://mysite/Student/Index
- http://mysite/Student/MyJobs
- http://mysite/Staff/Applications

etc....

Any users can go onto some areas/urls of the website freely from other Intranet portals and I don't know where should I write the code to fulfill that criteria.  The problem is that, there is no specific entry point to the application like http://mysite/Login or Authenticate, etc.  If there is, I could load all users details and rights from AD on that single entry point.

In MVC5 era, I used Custom Global Authorize Attribute and put it on the BaseController is inherited from all other controllers to load that AD data.  I put the AD's data into Session on the first hit and use the Static Class to display on Views and use in Controllers.  But when I did some research in MVC Core, some say that it's outdated and I should use the Authorize Policy instead of custom Authorize Attributes.

Getting the data from Active Directory is already achieved by using my old webservices and we don't need to worry about .Net core not supporting AD yet.

I looked at the tutorials about Policy and saw something about Claims and Custom User Managers.  I couldn't decide which one I should use to load data from Active Directory to the object (probably Scoped Object DI) which lasts for the whole user's session.

Should I load the data onto claims attributes 
Eg...

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim("UserName", "John.Smith", ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer));
claims.Add(new Claim("RefNo", "02343001", ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer));
claims.Add(new Claim("Email", "MyEmail@email.com", ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer));
```

Or Should I write customized SignInManager and IdentityUser?
Eg...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string RefNo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anywhere I could put my code to check AD and load data?
And should I store the data in that Claimed Object rather than using Session Data?

Could you guys please advise me?  Feel free to criticize if I miss anything and my idea is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in saying there's no System.DirectoryServices yet (it's on the backlog, I promise) so there are a couple of places to do this.

If you're already using Integrated Authentication you have SIDs for group membership, which are resolved when you call IsInRole(), so you can use role based membership (rather than Claims based) to solve basic authentication problems.

However if you want to support a forms based mechanism then you should look at using [the cookie middleware, raw](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html), to at least give you a simple login, calling your web service to validate your login. You could query your API in the controller code, and write an identity cookie. This cookie automatically encrypted and signed, so it can't be tampered with.

The problem comes when you want roles, and attributes. If you head down the cookie route you might be tempted to put all of those as claims in the identity before writing the identity out as a cookie. This might work, provided there are not too many - cookies have a maximum size (browser dependent, but under 4k usually). You can used chunked cookies, but there's a performance impact here. Instead you might use a reference cookie, where you put in a reference to another store where the actual fully populated identity is stored, be it session, redis or something else.

Then in [the claims transformation middleware](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) you can pull the reference out, go to your store, and rehydrate the identity.

I'd honestly avoid trying to merge all of this into ASP.NET Identity. That's mean to be the sole source for user information in an application, and in your case that's not true. Your sole source should be AD.

There's also a port of [Novell's ldap library](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) to core, which should stand in nicely for DirectoryServices should you want to avoid your web services approach.

Comment: Thanks and I think I will stick with the Web Services Approach which I am already using in all other projects.

I have already watched the 2 Videos of yours about Auths and I am trying to do the same thing by creating RequirementHandler and Policy and put it on the BaseController.  

So, the information from AD will be loaded whenever a user hits any area in my website.  Claims Transformation Middleware is something I didn't know.  I will do some research about it too.

Comment: Doing it in a policy is fine, just cache it for a while for performance.

Comment: The new library for AD <--> ASPNetCore is released a week ago.
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.ActiveDirectory/).
Would like to check with you that, It's only for Windows Authentication, right?  It has nothing to do with getting the data from AD and Vice Versa.  Thanks.

Comment: That's not an official package. I have no idea who wrote that.

Comment: And yes it looks like it's just for ntlm